# I got Error: Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'String', what should i do?

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I use Dio to getting response, and this is my modeling classes:

```dart
import 'package:shoppingcenter/screens/homePage.dart';

class MALL {
  late final int id;
  late final String name;
  late final String images;

  MALL({required this.id, required this.name, required this.images});

  factory MALL.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    final id = data['id'];
    final name = data['name'];
    final images = data['images'];
    return MALL(id: id, name: name, images: images);
  }
}

class City {
  final List<MALL> malls;

  City({required this.malls});

  factory City.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    final mallData = data['malls'] as List<dynamic>?;
    final malls = mallData != null ? mallData.map((mallData) => MALL.fromJson(mallData)).toList() : <MALL>[];
    return City(malls: malls);
  }
}
```

I get this error when I try to use my classes:

```
Error: Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'String'
```

My JSON is:

```
{
  "malls": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "city center",
      "images": "city.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

My response code:

```dart
Future<List<MALL>> get() async {
  final dio = Dio();
  var url = 'My URL';
  Response response = await dio.get(url);
  City api = City.fromJson(response.data);
  return api.malls;
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Your JSON is not a list of malls... did you type it by hand? Can you please copy/paste the *actual* JSON you are using? Can you post an example JSON of two malls?

Comment: What type is your respone.data? Looks like it's a string. Try to decode it to a Map with jsonDecode(response.data)

Comment: Error: FormatException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON 
now i get this error
@targiasld

Answer (score 0):

`response.data` is a `String`. You need to decode it to `Map`:

```dart
City api = City.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.data));
```

Comment: Error: FormatException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON

now i get this error

Comment: It looks like not a json. If api request must return a json but returns html or xml - I think you need to check the api request. Look attentive to response.data - may be the api returns an error. Or may be you need to add a header to your request Content type application/json.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your answers:

Your API doesn't return a JSON, it returns a HTML file. It tries to parse the html file with `jsonDecode`. Check your API with Postman, why it doesn't return a response in JSON format.

Comment: I checked it, its true